# How to get Apple Watch display radius?

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, wkinterfacecontroller

Is there some way to get the display radius? I tried to use `contentSafeAreaInsets` but they are 0 inside `willActivate()` and `awake(withContext:)` which is very frustrating.